# How can we have different handlers to subscribe messages from different topics using spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-dsl

I wrote my first spring integration application which uses the mqtt broker to subscribe messages from different topics which are coming from a device. The device is publishing the messages and the client(Code) is accessing those messages using same topics.

I added a handler for accessing the messages coming from the broker and use it further in classes. Now, in my case, I want to have different handlers for different topics so that they can all be mapped to different VO classes and use it further in business logic.

As I know, I want to create only one connection to the broker, one channel but different topics can come and they should be handled in different handlers for the same connection. How Can I achieve that?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MqttJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MqttJavaApplication.class);
        SpringApplication.run(MqttJavaApplication.class,args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inbound() {
        String clientId = "uuid-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("tcp://localhost:1883", clientId,"camera/status");
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
//        adapter.setOutputChannelName("mqttInputChannel");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(SubScribeMessages.class.getMethods()).findFirst());
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inbound())
                .transform(p -> p)
                .handle("addTopics","handlHere")
                .get();
    }

    @Component
    public class MyService{

        @Autowired
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter;

        @Bean
        public String addTopics()
        {
            if(adapter.getTopic().length>0)
            {
                adapter.addTopic("camera/+/counts"); //new topic 
                adapter.addTopic("camera/+/live_counts"); //new topic
            }
            return "";
        }

        // topic "camera/+/counts" is handled here but other messages also come here, how do we handle other topics in separate handlers?
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
        public void handleHere(@Payload Object mess) throws JsonProcessingException {
            String[]  topics = adapter.getTopic();
            for(String topic:topics)
                System.out.println(topic); // How can I get topic name which is using a wildcard?
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json=mess.toString();
            System.out.println(json);
            CountVo countVo = objectMapper.readValue(json, CountVo.class);
            if (!countVo.equals(null))
                System.out.println(countVo.getIrisysCounts().get(0).getName());

        }
    }

}
```

**Additional Question**

How Can I get the full topic name when using a wildcard? The actual topic which was published but caught by wildcard.

Please help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mosquitto; please don’t use that tag unless it does.

Comment: Sure. I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a router (`.route(...)`); you can route on the `MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC` header (which contains the topic name) to different flows for each topic.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

**EDIT**

The simplest router is to simply map the topic names to channel names. Here is an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67391175Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67391175Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory pahoClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory pahoClientFactory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions connectionOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connectionOptions.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" });
        pahoClientFactory.setConnectionOptions(connectionOptions);
        return pahoClientFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow(DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory pahoClientFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("testClient",
                        pahoClientFactory, "topic1", "topic2"))
                .route("headers['" + MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC + "']")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("topic1")
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    System.out.println("message from topic1 " + payload + ": " + headers);
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("topic2")
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    System.out.println("message from topic2 " + payload + ": " + headers);
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }

}
```

> `message from topic1 test: {mqtt_receivedRetained=false, mqtt_id=1, mqtt_duplicate=false, id=1d950bce-aa47-7e3b-1a0d-e4d01ed707de, mqtt_receivedTopic=topic1, mqtt_receivedQos=1, timestamp=1620250633090}`

> `message from topic2 test: {mqtt_receivedRetained=false, mqtt_id=2, mqtt_duplicate=false, id=7e9c3f51-c148-2b18-3588-ed27e93dae19, mqtt_receivedTopic=topic2, mqtt_receivedQos=1, timestamp=1620250644602}`

Comment: Yeah, I think this would help. Although I still have to implement and check if it's working the way it is supposed. Any examples of implemented code would help.  Thanks a lot for your help. Will confirm.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: It's easiest to use Spring Boot's dependency management, so only the Boot version is in my pom (2.4.5). Even if you don't use Boot, just add `spring-integration-mqtt` to your pom and it will bring in the dependencies transitively with the right versions. For example spring-integration-mqtt 5.4.6 brings in spring- ramework jars at 5.3.6.

Comment: Thanks Gary...I am checking this and I am getting this issue while running, are you aware about this? -> `org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [bean 'mqttInFlow.mqtt:inbound-channel-adapter#0'; defined in: 'com.harman.MqttJavaApplication'; from source: 'bean method mqttInFlow'] with key 'mqttInFlow.mqtt:inbound-channel-adapter#0'; nested exception is javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character : in value`

Comment: Add `spring-integration-jmx`.

Comment: Yeah that worked again, thanks! but how do I handle wildcards in this case? Say for example I have a topic which is camera/+/counts and we create a handler in flow2, but when the message comes from publisher say camera/100056/counts -> where 100056 is an ID, the application would throw an error as -> `failed to look up MessageChannel with name "camera/100056/counts" in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named "camera/100056/counts" available`

Comment: If you need a different flow for each id, you can use [dynamic flow registration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows). If you have a small number of flows and somehow know which flow to route a particular id to, you need to use a different router type to do the lookup - see the documentation I pointed you to about the different routers.

Comment: Hey Gary, please see my answer below.

Comment: I don't understand your concern; you could use `.route("headers['" + MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC + "'].endsWith('counts') ? 'channel1' : 'channel2'")`. If you just want to discard records from other topics (which seems odd), you can make `channel2` a `NullChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gary! I think the answer you gave on routing can only take the defined topics, not on wildcards or for that matter any other regex. I could not understand how dynamic routing would help me.

Turns out, I can add wildcards when initializing bean and can handle using the service activator on the inputchannel using the adapter.

Like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MqttJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MqttJavaApplication.class,args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inbound() {
        String clientId = "uuid-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("tcp://localhost:1883", clientId, "irisys/V4D-20230143/status"   );
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Component
    public class MyService{

        @Autowired
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter;

        @Bean
        public String addTopics()
        {
            if(adapter.getTopic().length>0)
            {
                adapter.addTopic("camera/+/counts");
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
        public MessageHandler handler() {
            return new MessageHandler() {

                @SneakyThrows
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                    System.out.println(message.getPayload());
                    System.out.println(message.getHeaders());
                    if(message.getHeaders().get("mqtt_receivedTopic").toString().contains("counts"))
                    {
                        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        String json=message.getPayload().toString();
                        System.out.println(json);
                        CountVo countVo = objectMapper.readValue(json, CountVo.class);
                        if (!countVo.equals(null))
                            System.out.println(countVo.getIrisysCounts().get(0).getName());
                    }

                }

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think that there is better way than this? I couldn't think of anything other than this.

Comment: I don't understand your concern; you could use `.route("headers['" + MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC + "'].endsWith('counts') ? 'channel1' : 'channel2'")`. If you just want to discard records from other topics (which seems odd), you can make `channel2` a `NullChannel`.